# Calling member function template of class template

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I have the following program (sorry, it is rather complex, but already a boiled-down version from a larger program):

```
#include <stdio.h>

// two different vector types

template <typename T, int N>
struct Vec1
{
  Vec1() { puts("Vec1()"); }
};

template <typename T, int N>
struct Vec2
{
  Vec2() { puts("Vec2()"); }
};

// a function wrapper

template <typename T, int N>
struct MyFct
{
  template <template <typename, int> class VEC>
  static inline VEC<T,N>
  apply()
  {
    puts("MyFct::apply()");
    return VEC<T,N>();
  }
};

// tester

#if 0
template <typename T, int N, template <typename, int> class FCT>
struct Tester
{
  static inline void test()
  {
    puts("Tester::test");
    Vec1<T,N> v1;
    v1 = FCT<T,N>::apply<Vec1>();
    Vec2<T,N> v2; 
    v2 = FCT<T,N>::apply<Vec2>();
  }
};
#endif

int
main()
{
  MyFct<float,16>::apply<Vec1>();
  MyFct<int,32>::apply<Vec2>();
  // Tester<float,16,MyFct>::test();
  return 0;
}
```

The program compiles with `#if 0` (without `Tester`), but with `#if 1` (with `Tester`) I get the error message

```
g++ -Wall -o templatetemplate2a templatetemplate2a.C
templatetemplate2a.C: In static member function 'static void Tester<T, N, FCT>::test()':
templatetemplate2a.C:41:30: error: missing template arguments before '>' token
     v1 = FCT<T,N>::apply<Vec1>();
                              ^
templatetemplate2a.C:41:32: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
     v1 = FCT<T,N>::apply<Vec1>();
                                ^
templatetemplate2a.C:43:30: error: missing template arguments before '>' token
     v2 = FCT<T,N>::apply<Vec2>();
                              ^
templatetemplate2a.C:43:32: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
     v2 = FCT<T,N>::apply<Vec2>();
```

This is surprising since the *direct* application (see `main()`) of `apply<Vec1>()` and `apply<Vec2>()` works fine. However, if I do the same inside of `Tester::test()`, I get the error messages. Is this some name-scope issue? Are the template classes `Vec1` and `Vec2` unknown inside of `Tester`? How can I make them known? Or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply()` is a member function template, you need to use the [keyword template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) to tell the compiler that it's a template, when calling it with dependent name. Note the difference between `FCT<T,N>` and `MyFct<float,16>`, the former depends on template parameters `FCT`, `T` and `N`, while the later doesn't.

> Inside a template definition, template can be used to declare that a dependent name is a template.

e.g.

```
v1 = FCT<T,N>::template apply<Vec1>();
v2 = FCT<T,N>::template apply<Vec2>();
```